# Get information about the Visitor (Javascript / PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, client-side, server-side, browser-detection

I am trying to create a website which can track/analyze the visitor and gather as much information as possible about the visitor. I have already found services which were not free, but they have provided every piece of information about the user who is visiting the website.

Is there a solution for that which is free yet effective like the paid ones out there? Also, should I use client side or server side scripting? Which is more reliable?

The main reason that I'm trying to gather these information is because I'd like to know more about my website visitors and eliminate the fraudsters or cheaters by analyzing their information. Or is there another good solution for that?

I'm sorry if this is a weird question, I'm quite new in this field this is why I'd like to know more about it.

**EDIT:** I have already tried Google Analytics, but it is not really good in my case.

Comment: Does Google Analytics not provide enough information for you, what information are you looking to capture?

Comment: What kind of information do you want?  "As much as possible" actually has a lot of depth to it.  What specifically do you think will help identify the fraudsters?  Usually, it's best to approach the problem by knowing specifically what you want out of it.

Comment: I'd like to capture information from user agent through window size till masked ip addresses and so on. This site has pretty much info, but they don't provide their code: http://browserspy.dk/

Comment: I suspect that Googling each of those bits of information will give you ideas how to collect each one and answer the browser vs. server side question for each bit. For example, I searched for "javascript ip address" and the 1st item told me that javascript isn't the right place but the server side is easy.

Comment: @RadicalActi Keep in mind that not all HTTP clients are browsers. [Scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping), for example, is typically done through scripts and HTTP protocol libraries where no window exists and User-Agents can be faked. They often won't even execute client-side code for gathering some analytics, with the exception of [headless browsers](http://blog.arhg.net/2009/10/what-is-headless-browser.html). [Web crawlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) are included in this; though, they're typically consistent with their User-Agents.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski Thank you for the heads up. Is there an possbile solution to detect if the user agent is fake?

Comment: @RadicalActi Not really. The value is determined by the client, so servers have to trust that it's accurate. What you might try is looking into [CSRF prevention](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). This won't stop all, but should at least lessen the occurrences by making it more difficult/troublesome to accomplish.

Comment: what information can the browser tell you that would "eliminate the fraudsters or cheaters " ?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to Geo Locate your visitors, and discover their physical location based off their IP, MaxMind has a great service with a free option.

http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing